# Creating an asynchronous "ReadFileMany()" on top of ReadFile()

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++, readfile

I'm trying to make a function, `ReadFileMany`, which imitates `ReadFile`'s interface, which is given a *list* of (offset, length) pairs to read from, and which reads all portions of the file asynchronously.

I'm doing this inside `ReadFileMany` by using `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` to direct a thread pool thread to wait for I/O to complete, so that it can call `ReadFile` again to read the next portion of the file, etc.

The trouble I'm running into is that I can't seem to be able to mimic a certain behavior of `ReadFile`.
Specifically, *file* handles can themselves be used like events, *without* the need for an event handle:

```
OVERLAPPED ov = {0};
DWORD nw;
if (ReadFile(hFile, buf, buf_size, &nw, &ov))
{
    if (WaitForSingleObject(hFile, INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

but of course, if the user waits on a file handle, he might get a notification that an *intermediate* read has complete, rather than the final read.

So, inside `ReadFileMany`, I have no choice but to pass an `hEvent` parameter to `ReadFile` for *all but the last portion*.

The question is, **is there any way to still allow the user to wait for the file handle to become signaled when all the portions have been read?**

At first the answer seems obvious: just avoid passing an event handle when reading the *last* portion!
That works fine if the read will be successful, but not if there are errors. If `ReadFile` starts suddenly returning an error on the last read, I will need to set the file handle to a signaled state *manually* in order to allow the reader to wake up from his potential call to `WaitForSingleObject(hFile)`.

**But there seems to be no way to set a *file handle* to a signaled state without performing actual I/O**... so this is where I get stuck: is there any way for me to write this function so that it behaves like `ReadFile` on the outside, or is it impossible to do it correctly?

Comment: Where did you ever get the idea that you can pass a file handle to `WaitForSingleObject()`?  A file handle is not a waitable object, so you cannot wait on it.

Comment: Is [ReadFileScatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) what you're trying to write?

Comment: @Damon: No; it's the exact opposite, actually. The "scatter" in `ReadFileScatter` refers to the memory buffer (scattered pages in memory), whereas the "many" in `ReadFileMemory` refers to different portions of the file.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, you actually can. (Try it.) Apparently the `ReadFile` documentation seems to avoid mentioning it, but if you look at [`ZwReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567072.aspx), you'll see this is perfectly valid, and that file handles can become signaled just like event handles: *"The calling thread can synchronize to the completion of the read operation by waiting on the file handle. The handle is signaled each time that an I/O operation that was issued on the handle completes."*

Comment: @Mehrdad: according to that doc, it only works if the file was opened with `SYNCHRONIZE` access rights, and only if there is only one I/O operation being performed at a time. The waiting should be done with `ZwWaitForSingleObject()`. Neither the `CreateFile()`, `ReadFile()`, or `WaitFor...()` docs mention anything about file handles being supported as waitable objects, so I really would not rely on that behavior. `ZwReadFile()` is a lower level API than `ReadFile()`, so don't mix lower level and higher level API semantics together.

Comment: @Remy: Well, if you consider it an abstraction violation (I don't) then you can pretend like I'd prefixed everything with `Zw` and was asking about the native API; the problem is still the same.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I also just saw a paragraph at the end of the [`GetOverlappedResult` documentatin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683209.aspx) which says, *"If the `hEvent` member of the `OVERLAPPED` structure is `NULL`, the system uses the state of the `hFile` handle to signal when the operation has been completed."* It's discouraged all right, but still a valid use case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to read multiple sections of a single file, I would simply allocate an array of `OVERLAPPED` structures, one for each requested section of the file, kick off all of the `ReadFile()` calls at one time, and then use `WaitForMultipleObjects()` to wait for all of the I/Os to finish, eg:

```
struct sReadInfo
{
    OVERLAPPED ov;
    LPVOID pBuffer;
    DWORD dwNumBytes;
    DWORD dwNumBytesRead;
    bool bPending;

    sReadInfo()
    {
        memset(&ov, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
        pBuffer = NULL;
        dwNumBytes = 0;
        dwNumBytesRead = 0;
        bPending = false;

        ov.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
        if (!ov.hEvent) throw std::exception();
    }

    ~sReadInfo()
    {
        CloseHandle(hEvent);
    }
};
```

.

```
bool error = false;

try
{
    std::vector<sReadInfo> ri(numSections);

    std::vector<HANDLE> h;
    h.reserve(numSections);

    for(int i = 0; i < numSections; ++i)
    {
        ULARGE_INTEGER ul;
        ul.QuadPart = ...; // desired file offset to read from

        sReadInfo *r = &ri[i];

        r->ov.Offset = ul.LowPart;
        r->ov.OffsetHigh = ul.HighPart;

        r->pBuffer = ...; // desired buffer to read into
        r->dwNumBytes = ...; // desired number of bytes to read

        if (!ReadFile(hFile, r->pBuffer, r->dwNumBytes, &r->dwNumBytesRead, &r->ov))
        {
            if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
                throw std::exception();

            r->bPending = true;
            h.push_back(r->ov.hEvent);
        }
    }

    if (!h.empty())
    {
        if (WaitForMultipleObjects(h.size(), &h[0], TRUE, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            throw std::exception();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numSections; ++i)
    {
        sReadInfo *r = &ri[i];

        if (r->bPending)
            GetOverlappedResult(hFile, &r->ov, &r->dwNumBytesRead, FALSE);

        // ...
    }
}
catch (const std::exception &)
{
    CancelIo(hFile);
    return false;
}

return true;
```

Comment: Interesting... wouldn't that cause a lot of thrashing on the disk? And how would the user know that **all** the reads have completed, rather than just one of them? Seems like we still have the same problem as before.

Comment: It is still overlapped I/O, so Windows can schedule the actual disc activity as it sees fit. If you look more closely, I set the `bWaitAll` parameter of `WaitForMultipleObjects()` to TRUE so it will not exit until **all** of the requested reads have completed.

Comment: It looks like you completely missed the question, which had to do with waiting on **file** handles. You're waiting on event handles instead, which is already something I mentioned in my question, but which doesn't provide the same interface to the problem as the one I was asking about. Reread the question carefully to understand what the problem really is.